# What does the 'dump' method do in android.location.Location and why does it have no documentation?

Tags: android, geolocation, location

There is a method called [dump](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#dump%28android.util.Printer,%20java.lang.String%29) in the Location class but it has no documentation associated with it.

What exactly does it do? And also, if it's known, why does it have no documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's here for debugging purposes only.

Here is the source code of the implementation:

```
public void dump(Printer pw, String prefix) {
         pw.println(prefix + "mProvider=" + mProvider + " mTime=" + mTime);
         pw.println(prefix + "mLatitude=" + mLatitude + " mLongitude=" + mLongitude);
         pw.println(prefix + "mHasAltitude=" + mHasAltitude + " mAltitude=" + mAltitude);
         pw.println(prefix + "mHasSpeed=" + mHasSpeed + " mSpeed=" + mSpeed);
         pw.println(prefix + "mHasBearing=" + mHasBearing + " mBearing=" + mBearing);
         pw.println(prefix + "mHasAccuracy=" + mHasAccuracy + " mAccuracy=" + mAccuracy);
         pw.println(prefix + "mExtras=" + mExtras);
     }
```

Comment: You can use it like:
```location.dump(new LogPrinter(Log.DEBUG, "TAG"), "prefix")```